# Initialize a ComplexType variable inside a Class (SoapClient)

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

Hey everyone, I am trying to consume a WebService using PHP `SoapClient`.
Now, everything is working fine until I try to use a ComplexType variable.
I am getting a `NullPointerException` from the web service.

Here is an example ComplexType variable's class:

```
class A {
public $var1 = 0; //int
public $var2; //Object: B
}
```

Now, I am making an object like this:

```
$a = new A();
$a->var2 = new B();
```

But, this has to be done every time I make an object of A.
Is there a method to initialize `$var2` in `class A`, without using the constructors for it, like we are doing for `$var1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, is possible if using PHP [overloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php)

```
class A
{
  public $var1 = 0;
  /* note $var2 cannot declare here */

  public function __get($name)
  {
    switch ($name)
    {
      case 'var2':
        return new B();
        break;
    }
  }
}

class B
{
  public $var3 = 1;
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->name = 'this is class b';
  }
}

$a = new A();
var_dump( $a->var2 );
var_dump( $a->var2->var3 );
var_dump( $a->var2->name );
```

Is called using `$a->var2` instead of `$a->$var2`

Comment: . thanks for that solution. works wonderfully. and also for pointing that mistake in my code.. :P